# How do I make a responsive headder that looks like this? *see provided image*

Tags: html, css

I am in the middle of making a header for a website, it has to be responsive, the picture I provided is a rough mockup of the header that I want to make. I have tried to make the shape with an SVG path but I couldn't find a way to make it completely responsive, so I was wondering if there was a better way.

what I've tried:
*use the pictures to see the result

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

#topLine {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
  height: 2vh;
  width: 110vw;
  background: linear-gradient(178.8deg, rgb(255, 95, 30) 0%, rgb(255, 95, 30) 60%, rgb(185, 15, 0) 100%);
}

#topLineLogo {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0%;
  height: 8vh;
  width: 40vw;
  background: linear-gradient(179.6deg, rgb(255, 95, 30) 0%, rgb(255, 95, 30) 40%, rgb(185, 15, 0) 100%);
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
  z-index: -1;
}

#topLineLogoFill {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0%;
  transform: translate(10%, 0%) rotate(-3deg);
  width: 50vw;
  height: 5vh;
  background: rgb(255, 95, 30);
  z-index: -2;
}

svg polyline,
svg line,
svg path {
  fill: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  stroke: rgb(225, 95, 10);
}
```

```html
<div id="topLine"></div>
<div id="topLineLogo"></div>
<div id="topLineLogoFill"></div>
<svg height="15vh" width="90vw" viewBox="0 0 1000 100">
     <path d="M363,44.2 Q363,3.6 700,8.6" />
</svg>
```

[A rough mockup of the desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/coZG8.png)

[The result of what I've tried](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MgHRL.png)

[The result of what I've tried upon resizing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9n48.png)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like that. You can adjust the curve by changing in `.background__white` the value of `border-radius` and/or `height`.

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}
.background__orange {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: orange;
}
.background__white {
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 2000px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 40%;
  top: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="background__orange">
  </div>
  <div class="background__white">
  </div>
</div>
```